# Neo4j graph database relationship with properties

Tags: database, neo4j, shortest-path, graph-traversal

I'm developing something for learning graph databases.I'm finding the shortest path that query in the following segment:

```
start n=node(5),m=node(45) match p=shortestPath(n-[*..1000]->m) return p,length(p)
```

But I have problem about that.That query will return the shortest path and not considered with ROUTE properties.I mean, I want to get shortest path with a relation, if there is exist same property.

> Node A ==> :RELATION(ROUTE_ID=180) ==> Node B ==>
>   :RELATION(ROUTE_ID=180) ==> NODE C ==> :RELATION(ROUTE_ID=197)

When I call the normal shortest path function, it gives me relationships by random properties.I want to focus on properties also.What is the keyword for that? 
How can I fix that problem or How can I improve that query?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding you... You mean, you want the shortest path between two nodes but using only one specific type on links (e.g. only `RELATION` links)? And, also, specifying some conditions that must be satisfied by the links (e.g. property `p` must be equal to 6, or bigger than 14)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all relationships with the ROUTE_ID property have a specific relationship type, say 'ROUTE', then you can do this:

```
START n=node(5), m=node(45)
MATCH p=shortestPath(n-[:ROUTE*..1000]->m)
RETURN p,length(p);
```

Otherwise, you can do this:

```
START n=node(5), m=node(45)
MATCH p=shortestPath(n-[r*..1000]->m)
WHERE all(x IN r WHERE has(x.ROUTE_ID))
RETURN p,length(p);
```

The former approach should be much faster.

Comment: Actually it might make sense to move the ROUTE-ID into the relationship-type itself, so using ROUTE_180 as relationship-type: `MATCH p=shortestPath(n-[:ROUTE_180*..1000]->m)`

Comment: That's what I'm talking about.I can't change my relation types because If I change it then I must change my all algorithm.Thank you, cybersam.Kind regards.

Comment: What about the minimum number of ROUTE_ID.I mean, I want minimum RouteID number should 5 or more?